# How to run Java command line script through python to return object?

Tags: java, python, windows, python-2.7

I have written a java class

```
public class Uploadfiles {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(args[0]);
        //uploadFile(args[0]);
    }
```

I have converted it to jar by right click project>Export> Runable jar> Package required libraries into generated Jar. 
I have run the command to execute through command line

```
java -classpath JavaSeleniumLibs.jar javaSeleniumClasses.Uploadfiles Test
```

The output is

```
Test
```

I wanted to run the same commandline script through python and i use the method below

```
import os
def runCommandline():
    print os.system("java -classpath JavaSeleniumLibs.jar javaSeleniumClasses.Uploadfiles Test")
```

I wanted the output "Test" to be printed as when done from commandline. How to do it?
How to return value from the executed Java function? like "The script is successfully executed"? Can I return other objects from the java function to the python os.system command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running shell command from Python and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output)

Comment: I use python 2.7 , I believe subprocess module is for python 3 version

Comment: see  this https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: You can always redirect stdout to somewhere else and read its content.